# How to resolve "Member access into incomplete type" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad, objective-c++

I am trying to integrate iAd into a cocos2d-x project as described in:
http://becomingindiedev.blogspot.com.es/2015/02/integrating-iad-in-cocos2d-x-v3x.html

AdBanner.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>  
 #import <iAd/iAd.h>  
 @class RootViewController;   
 @interface AdBanner : NSObject<ADBannerViewDelegate>  
 {  
   UIWindow* window;  
   RootViewController* rootViewController;  
   ADBannerView* adBannerView;  
   bool adBannerViewIsVisible;  
 }
```

AdBanner.mm

```
@implementation AdBanner

 -(id)init  
 {  
   if(self=[super init])  
   {  
     adBannerViewIsVisible = YES;  
     rootViewController =  
       (RootViewController*) [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];  
     window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];  
     [self createAdBannerView];  
   }  
   return self;  
 }  

-(void)layoutAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect bannerFrame = adBannerView.frame;
    //Has the banner an advestiment?
    if ( adBannerView.bannerLoaded && adBannerViewIsVisible )
    {
        NSLog(@"Banner has advertisement");
        bannerFrame.origin.y = window.bounds.size.height - bannerFrame.size.height;
    } else
    {
        NSLog( @"Banner has NO advertisement" );
        //if no advertisement loaded, move it offscreen
        bannerFrame.origin.y = window.bounds.size.height;
    }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animated ? 0.25 : 0.0 animations:^{
        [rootViewController.view layoutIfNeeded]; //Member access into incomplete type "RootViewController"
        adBannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
    }];
}
@end
```

The line at the bottom in AdBanner.mm gives the error:

```
    [rootViewController.view layoutIfNeeded]; //Member access into incomplete type "RootViewController"
```

How do I resolve this ?

Comment: `rootViewController` looks like a pointer, try `->`?

Comment: This is objective-c++ code.

Comment: It was tagged c++ before vsoftco edited it.....

Comment: Do you have `#import "RootViewController.h"`  in AdBanner.mm?

Comment: The comment by @Paulw11 is what you need. The .h file only has a forward declaration of `RootViewController`. The .mm needs to actually import the header for `RootViewController`. Paul - post it as an answer.

Comment: @Paulw11 You are correct. You can post it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have declared `RootViewController` as a forward class declaration in your .h file using the `@Class` directive, but you haven't imported RootViewController.h in your ADBanner.mm file.

This means that the compiler knows that there is some class `RootViewController` but doesn't know anything more about it - its superclass, methods or properties. As such it can't confirm that it actually has a method `layoutIfNeeded`.

Adding `#import "RootViewController.h"` to the top of ADBanner.mm will give the compiler the information it needs and resolve the error.